# scroll change listener on blackberry

Tags: blackberry, java-me

When I execute the following code on a simulator it throws stackoverflow error.

I think the error came for, Each newhorizontalScroll value when I scroll.

How to avoid it or how to calculate the final horizontal scroll value?

```
int customfiledwidth = Display.getWidth()/3;


HorizontalFieldManager horizontalScrollLayout = new HorizontalFieldManager(HorizontalFieldManager.HORIZONTAL_SCROLL)
horizontalScrollLayout.setScrollListener(this);

// i add number of customfield on horizontalscrolllayout.....

public void scrollChanged(Manager manager, int newHorizontalScroll,int newVerticalScroll) 
{
    {

        horizontalScrollLayout.setHorizontalScroll(newHorizontalScroll);
        int fieldIndex =horizontalScrollLayout.getFieldAtLocation(newHorizontalScroll+customfieldwidth,0);
        Field f = horizontalScrollLayout.getField(fieldIndex);
        f.setFocus();
        invalidate();
        }}
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting into an infinite loop pretty much by calling `setHorizontalScroll()` on the same Field that you are listening to its scroll. I would remove this line and see if your code works.

Comment: Hi. I deleted the line.. But , When i slowly move the horizontal scroll bar, its throw stack overflow error. what should i do for this error. or any other idea.. pls help to me.

Comment: The problem only came for this line.       setHorizontalScroll().  I deleted the line.. then where could i use this line on my program. Its for center position after scrolling.  Pls give any idea.

Comment: i need to move the field on center after scrolling.. pls give any idea.

Comment: Are you trying to move a field or set the focus on a Field? If you're trying to set the focus, I'd suggest getting rid of a the `+ customFieldWidth`