# How to override default scrolling behavior in OS 6

Tags: blackberry

I have a custom extension of VerticalFieldManager that automatically scrolls itself to display data to the user.  Both above and below that VFM, there are other components that the user can interact with.  On OS5, this works perfectly and exactly how I expect.  On OS6, with the built-in "smooth scrolling" feature, when the user tries to scroll from the fields above the VFM to the fields below, the VFM is scrolled by the user's input before transferring focus to the fields below the VFM.

Is there any way to override this behavior and tell the OS to leave my VFM alone?  In OS5, this was a simple as making the VFM non-focusable.

I have tried fiddling with the vertical adjustment and vertical quantization on the VFM with no luck.  The VFM never actually receives focus, the OS just scrolls it.  I assume the OS thinks that it is being helpful, but it is not! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a solution by overriding the `navigationMovement` function in the parent Manager, something like this:

```
protected boolean navigationMovement(int dx, int dy, int status, int time) {
    if (getField(getFieldWithFocusIndex()) == tabbar) {
        Field f = tabbar.getFieldWithFocus();
        if (f == lastTabButton) {
            if (dy > 0) {
                tabData.setFocus();
                return true;
            }
        } else if (f == firstTabButton) {
            if (dy < 0) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    } else if (getField(getFieldWithFocusIndex()) == tabData) {
        MyTab tab = (MyTab) tabs.get(tabData);
        if (tab != null && !tab.willHandleNavigationMovement(dx, dy)) {
            if (dy != 0) {
                if (dy < 0)
                    lastTabButton.setFocus();
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return super.navigationMovement(dx, dy, status, time);
}
```

You will see in the code above that I had to also override the behavior when scrolling up from the very top and scrolling down from the very bottom because the OS was again taking over and "helping" me scroll the non-focusable VFM.

Answer (score 1):

You could possibly mess with `nextFocus()` in the parent Manager to just skip the middle VFM. Maybe also override `onFocus()` for the middle on to just go to the next. I know that it should be doing this by setting it non-focusable, but maybe override `isFocusable()` to return false.

Comment: Thanks.  Already tried these.  The *focus* never enters the middle VFM.  It stays above the VFM until the VFM is scrolled to the bottom, at which point it jumps below the VFM.

Comment: Ah interesting...maybe add a ScrollChangeListener and if it does start reset it back to vertical 0 and change focus?

Comment: Another good idea, unfortunately, I do need the VFM to scroll, just when I tell it to programmatically, not when the user tries to move the cursor.  Hmm, but maybe if I make my scrolling logic hugely more complex I could tell the difference between my scrolling and the OS scrolling...

Comment: Using some flag to detect whether the scrolling is programmatic or native could help. Check this for an idea: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6883299/scroll-change-listener-on-blackberry/6883441#6883441

Comment: Well, messing with the scroll is a no-go: if I prevent the auto-scrolling, the OS will never let the focus move below the VFM.  Hmm, now I wonder about trying to capture the navigationMovement on the parent...

Comment: Can you programmatically change the VFM's extent so it doesn't need to scroll, then change it when you have a reason to?

Comment: Changing the extent and/or only adding the data to the VFM as it is needed are other possibilities, but then the VFM would still be subjected to the OS scrolling while it is busy scrolling itself.  Ugh.

Comment: GOOD NEWS!  I have got it working by overriding navigationMovement in the parent manager and carefully moving the focus back and forth, skipping the VFM completely.